# Usar duas funções no mesmo Javascript

Tags: javascript

Vou tentar ser o mais claro possível para que vocês possam me entender e ajudar, eu tenho o `javascript` seguinte.

```
function labelthumbs(e) {
document.write('<ul id="test">');
}
```

Ele usa a função `labelthumbs` e eu gostaria de adicionar outra função `labelthumbs2` nesse mesmo `javascript` sem precisar de duplicar e criar 2 `javascript` com funções diferentes.

Ao invés de:

```
function labelthumbs(e) {
document.write('<ul id="teste">');
}

function labelthumbs2(e) {
document.write('<ul id="teste">');
}
```

Eu gostaria de algo parecido com isso e que funcione:

```
function labelthumbs(e)
function labelthumbs2(e)
{
document.write('<ul id="teste">');
}
```

Comment: Não tem muito sentigo, por que ao invés disso não cria uma única função que faça as duas ações? Só não entendi por que está usando a variavel **e** que geralmente é usada pra eventos e pelo seu exemplo ambas funções fazem exatamente a mesma coisa.

Comment: Explique melhor a sua necessidade. Da forma que explicou não está fazendo sentido.

Comment: Não fez sentido para mim. Você poderia chamar a função mais de uma vez, ou colocar o conteúdo duplicado `<ul><ul>`. Acho que para podermos te ajudar precisamos entender qual seu objetivo com a função.

Comment: Ideal seria explicar qual a necessidade de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

se o que vc precisa é manter o mesmo código para as duas, vc pode fazer assim:

```
function labelthumbs(e){
    document.write('<ul id="teste">');
}
function labelthumbs2(e){
    labelthumbs(e);
}
```

Assim, quando editar a labelthumbs a resposta da outra muda tb

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi pretende criar duas funções idênticas fazendo apenas uma "declaração".

Uma possível solução seria:

```
var labelthumbs = labelthumbs2 = function(e){ document.write('<ul id="teste">'); }
```